# How do I find the max frequency of a number of an integer?

Tags: c++

This is the code that I have so far:

```
 #include <iostream>

    #define MAX(X,Y) ((X) > (Y) ? (X):(Y))

    int frequency(int n);

    int main()
    {
        int x;

        std::cout << "Please enter a sequence of numbers."
            << std::endl;
                std::cin >> x;

        std::cout << "The max frequency of " << x << " is "
              << frequency(x)
                << std::endl;

        return 0;
    }

    int frequency(int n)
    {
        int A[10] = {0}, rem;

        while (n != 0)
        {
            int rem = (n % 10);
            A[rem] += 1;
            n = (n / 10);
            std::cout << rem <<  '\t' << n
                << std::endl;
        }
        //MAX(A[rem], n);
    }
```

How can I modify this so that it prints out the the digit that has the most occurrence in an integer specified by a user?

Comment: you scan the array and find the largest value, then print the corresponding index. And this smells very strongly of "homework"... so... do it yourself.

Comment: @Aleksandar that is correct. But in case I enter a number like 122355 I need it to compare 2 and 5 and then give me the max of those two. Thats kinda where I'm stumped...

Comment: @theinternethobo that's something new, thanks for letting us know

Answer (score 1):

Just keep track of the max value in your loop:

```
    int A[10] = {};
    int max = 0;
    while (n != 0)
    {
        int rem = n % 10;
        ++A[rem];
        n /= 10;
        if( max == rem or A[max] > A[rem] )
            continue;
        if( A[rem] > A[max] or rem > max )
            max = rem;  
    }
    return max;
```

Note you create another `rem` together with array you better remove it as you do not use it.

Note2: there is nothing wrong with:

```
 A[rem] += 1;
 n = ( n / 10 );
```

it can be just expressed shortly in C++, as shown in my code.

Comment: Thank you @Slava! I know it seems like an easy program to write but I'm kind of new to C++ and I find it difficult to transform my ideas into physical program.

Comment: @theinternethobo pen and paper, man. Transform your ideas into a list of things that need to be done, transform the list into an ordered flow of what needs to be done when, and then transform the flow into code. Even if it turns out you're not good at step 3, there are tons of people who are and suck at steps 1 and 2. Find your niche and fill it.

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks for the tip man! I'll be sure to start doing that for now on.

Comment: @theinternethobo there is almost nothing specific to C++ in this program (except ++ and /= but that is mostly syntactic sugar). You need to learn how to express algorithm, not really matter in which language.